# Free energy density of two particle type gas and phase transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, mean-field-theory

I'm considering a gas consisting of $N = N_A + N_B$ particles of types $A$ and $B$. I have that

$$ \beta F = -N + N\ln\frac{\beta^{3/2}}{V}+N_A\ln N_A + N_B \ln N_B + \frac{\beta u_0}{V}N_A N_B + \mathcal{O}(N(N/V)^2)$$

Letting the proportion of $A$ particles $\phi =\frac{N_A}{N}$ be our order parameter, and assuming the mean field approximation where our order parameter is uniform across the whole system, the claim is then that

$$f\equiv \frac{F}{Vk T} = \beta A \phi(1-\phi) + B(\phi\ln\phi + (1-\phi)\ln(1-\phi) ) + C(T) + \mathcal{O}(\rho^3)$$

where $A,B>0$ are constants with respect to temperature. $k$ here is Boltzmann's constant. It is not clear to me where to begin in proving this.

Assuming that expression is true, we can take partial derivatives to find that the critical temperature is $T_c = \frac{A}{2B}$. Now, say that our gas is $70\%$ gas $A$ and $30\%$ gas $B$ and $T<T_c$. (sorry about the double use of $A$ and $B$) How do we know if the mixture divides into phases? Do we consider something like $f(\phi) + f(0.7-\phi)$ and study the minima? This is what I’m most curious about.

Comment: If $N_A$ is the total number of particles of type $A$, how does it can vary across the system? What is $C(T)$? What is $\rho$ in the second line?

Comment: I agree that that is a little unclear about the order parameter. C(T) is some function of T. I believe that $\rho$ is terms like $N/V$.

Comment: What is $u_0$? Why does the first equation seem to be dimensionally incorrect?

Comment: $u_0>0$ is a constant. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You haven’t explained how your equation is dimensionally correct. It doesn’t *look* dimensionally correct.

Comment: I see. Let's assume then that $u_0$ is positive constant such that the dimension questions work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same equation as the mean field Ising model (Curie-Weiss model). The interpretation as a mixture is detailed in Schroeder's *Thermal Physics* (5.4 Phase Transformations of Mixtures). You have a competition between the ideal mixing (entropy, taking $k_B = 1$):
$$
S = -(\phi\ln\phi+(1-\phi)\ln(1-\phi))
$$
which favours mixing at $\phi=1/2$ (maximise entropy). The magnetism analogue, this is again the entropy of your material which wants to randomise the material.

The other force is repelling energy between the types of particles (choosing the energy scale so that $u_0=1$):
$$
U = \phi(1-\phi)
$$
which favours separation at $\phi=0,1$ (minimise energy). In the magnetic analogue, this is ferromagnetic interaction which favours a homogeneous magnetisation.

The (molar) free energy is:
$$
\begin{align}
F &= U-TS\\
&= \phi(1-\phi)+T(\phi\ln\phi+(1-\phi)\ln(1-\phi))
\end{align}
$$
so for high temperature, entropy maximisation will win, while for low temperature, energy minimisation will win.

Yes, there is phase separation in a certain range of $\phi$. However, you cannot try to minimise $f$ since $\phi$ is prescribe. You rather need to compare $f$ with convex combinations of $f$ at different values and take the minimum. The former corresponds to a homogeneous phase, the latter represents a phase separation. Geometrically, this amounts to taking the convex hull of the epigraph of $f$. By definition of the critical temperature, there is a whole region of $\phi$ where it is the latter that is relevant below $T_c$.

Mathematically, you have essentially three equivalent ways of obtaining the result. Either you think in terms of $f$ and construct the solution with the common tangent line. The respective compositions of the phases being at the contact points of the common tangent. Alternatively, you can do a Maxwell construction by thinking in terms of $\mu = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$. The respective compositions are the endpoints of the straight segment. Finally, you can look at the Legendre transform of $f$ with respect to $\phi$ (the analogue of Gibbs free enthalpy in the case of volume):
$$
G(\mu) = F-\mu\phi
$$
which will have a swallowtail catastrophe and keep only the lower branch. The slopes on either end of the angular point will give you the respective compositions of the two phases.

Once you know the respective compositions, you just need to do convex combination of the two so that you obtain your prescribed $\phi$. You'll have a phase diagram in the $T,\phi$ plane where there is a whole region of phase separation that you can calculate. These methods are very general and apply for all kinds of phase separation like a gas-liquid transition, magnetism, distillation etc.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

In general, you cannot solve the problem analytically. You need to solve for the two compositions $\phi_A(T)>\phi_B(T)$ such that:
$$
\mu(\phi_A) = \mu(\phi_B) \\
G(\phi_A) = G(\phi_B)
$$
In your case:
$$
\begin{align}
\mu &= 1-2\phi+T\ln\frac{\phi}{1-\phi} \\
G &= F-\mu\phi \\
&= \phi^2+T\ln(1-\phi)
\end{align}
$$

You therefore have two equations and two unknowns, that you'll have to solve for numerically. As a sanity check, you already know two values:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= T_c & \phi_A &= \frac{1}{2} & \phi_B &= \frac{1}{2} \\
T &= 0 & \phi_A &= 1 & \phi_B &= 0
\end{align}
$$
You can use these values to solve for the compositions asymptotically close to these two special regimes (little homework for you).

In fact, due to symmetry, $\mu=0$ and $\phi_A = 1-\phi_B$ so you just need to find the minima of $F$, as you've noticed already. You therefore just need to solve for $\phi_A>1/2$ (to exclude the trivial solution $\phi_A = 1/2$):
$$
0 = 1-2\phi_A+T\ln\frac{\phi_A}{1-\phi_A} \\
$$

Once you have found $\phi_A,\phi_B$, if you are given $\phi_B<\phi<\phi_A$, you can deduce the proportion of each phase $0<x_A,x_B<1$ by linear interpolation:
$$
x_A+x_B = 1 \\
x_A\phi_A+x_B\phi_B = \phi
$$
so in your case:
$$
x_B = \frac{\phi_A-\phi}{2\phi_A-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! Could you possible show how you to do the calculation for the first method you described? I'm very new to this type of calculation.

Comment: If we plot $f$, we see that there are minima at $\phi = 0.15$ and $\phi=0.85$. I read in Section 5.4 of Schroeder that if we choose a value of $\phi$ that lies between these two values, our mixture will separate into phases. Can we use that here?

Comment: Thank you for the update! There may be a typo in your expression for $x_A$. I think it should be $x_A = \frac{\phi - \phi_B}{2\phi_A -1}$. Regardless, great answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, corrected